# Find the intersection of the open intervals

Tags: general-topology

I don't know how to find the intersection in these two problems.

The first problem asks for an example of a decreasing nest of open finite intervals

### ($a_1$, $b_1$) $\supseteq$ ($a_2$, $b_a$) $\supseteq$...

such that $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}$($a_k$, $b_k$)=$\emptyset$.

The second problems asks for an example of a decreasing nest of open intervals

### ($a_1$, $b_1$) $\supseteq$ ($a_2$, $b_a$) $\supseteq$...

such that $b_k$-$a_k$$\rightarrow$$0$ yet $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}$($a_k$, $b_k$)$\neq$$\emptyset$.

For the first problem, the book chooses the interval ($0$, $\frac 1k$) 
where the decreasing nest is

($0$, $1$) $\supseteq$ ($0$, $\frac12$) $\supseteq$ ($0$, $\frac13$)$\supseteq$...

And for the second problem, the book states that the correct interval is (-$\frac1n$, $\frac1n$) where the decreasing nest is

($-1$, $1$)$\supseteq$(-$\frac12$, $\frac12$)$\supseteq$(-$\frac13$, $\frac13$)$\supseteq$...

I understand the basic definition of an intersection to be the set of all the elements that belong to both A and B.

In the first problem, the book claims that the intersection is $\emptyset$. I'm not sure how this answer was achieved since the number $0$ occurs in all the intervals. Wouldn't the intersection be $0$?

I have the same dilemma for problem two. The books states that the intersection of the intervals is $0$. I'm not sure how that answer was reached either.

Can someone give me a better definition of the intersection of intervals and help me understand why these intersections were achieved?

Comment: "I'm not sure how this answer was achieved since the number 0 occurs in all the intervals."  No, it doesn't.  0 doesn't appear in *any* of the intervals.  the intervals consist of numbers *between* 0 and 1/k.  They do not include 0 or 1/k.

Comment: It's not intersection you are having a problem with.  It is intervals.  (a,b) is all the numbers x so that a< x < b.  a and b are *not* in the intervals.  So the first example.  There is no element in all the intervals.  The second 0 is in all the intervals.

Comment: $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}(0,\frac1k)=\emptyset$, where $(0,\frac1k)=\{x:0<x<\frac1k\}$. Indeed if $y\le0$ then $y$ does not belong to any $(0,\frac1k),$ and hence does not belong to the intersection. If $y>0$ then take $k>\frac1y$, then $y>\frac1k$ hence $y$ does not belong to $(0,\frac1k)$ (for this particular $k$), hence $y$ does not belong to the intersection. Note also that $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}[0,\frac1k]=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}[0,\frac1k)=\{0\}$ (singleton set containing the only element $0$), and the latter is different from $0$.(There is a convention that $0$ is the same as $\emptyset$)

Comment: I'm starting to understand. But I have one more question: after looking at a few more examples, it seems that the intersection must be an integer. In the first problem, $\frac14$ appears to occur in every interval. Yet the intersection is empty. Does the intersection have to be an integer?

Comment: No the intersection isn't an interger;  it's a set of numbers.  1/4 is not in (0,1/8).  The ... means that the sets never end.  (0,1/n), (0, 1/(n+1)) and so on ad infinitum.  What are the next trillion intervals?